# Why isn't this 'scroll to top' button code working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, scroll

I coded this "scrollToTop" button, so that when users scroll down, a button shows up that when clicked scrolls the page to the top. But for some reason it's not working.

There are no syntax errors being reported to the console...

Problem: What I see right now is, the css should be fine, because if I remove the display:none; the styling is all correct and the button shows in the right place, but the problem is, when I do scroll the page down, the button doesn't show, which means the javascript is not applying the fadeIn(); thing, but I do not know why...

**HTML**

```
 <a href="#" class="scrollToTop"></a>
```

**CSS**

```
 .scrollToTop{
    width:75px; 
    height:75px;
    padding:10px; 
    text-align:center; 
    text-decoration: none;
    position:fixed;
    top:100px;
    right:40px;
    opacity:0.5;
    display:none;
    background: url('images/scroll_up.png') no-repeat 0px 0px;
    background-size: 75px 75px;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s; /* For Safari 3.1 to 6.0 */
    transition: all 0.3s;
 }

 .scrollToTop:hover{
    text-decoration:none;
    top:90px;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s; /* For Safari 3.1 to 6.0 */
    transition: all 0.3s;
 }
```

**JavaScript/jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    //Check to see if the window is at the top, if not, then display scroll up button
    if ($(this).scrollTop() > 100) {
        $('.scrollToTop').fadeIn();
    } else {
        $('.scrollToTop').fadeOut();
    }

    //Click event to scroll up to top
    $('.scrollToTop').click(function(){
        $('html, body').animate({scrollTop : 0},750);
        return false;
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to check the current scroll position after every scroll event:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    //Check to see if the window is at the top, if not, then display scroll up button
    $(window).scroll(function() {
        if ($(this).scrollTop() > 100) {
            $('.scrollToTop').fadeIn();
        } else {
            $('.scrollToTop').fadeOut();
        }
    });

    //Click event to scroll up to top
    $('.scrollToTop').click(function(){
        $('html, body').animate({scrollTop : 0},750);
        return false;
    });
});
```

**[EXAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/z9mypfq7/)**

Comment: This should work, and as the fiddle shows, it does work, but in my website, it doesn't... The image is not showing, and the console reports nothing... :\

Comment: Ok, it is working now, I figured the problem out, the problem was that I had set overflow-x:hidden to the html/body, which was breaking this code for some reason. Thanks for the help anyway!

Answer (score 1):

This portion of code

```
if ($(this).scrollTop() > 100) {
    $('.scrollToTop').fadeIn();
} else {
    $('.scrollToTop').fadeOut();
}
```

is only being called once, when the document is ready. You need to be checking this as the user scrolls up and down, for example you could wrap in the window scroll event

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    //Check to see if the window is at the top, if not, then display scroll up button
    $(window).scroll(function() {
        if ($(this).scrollTop() > 100) {
            $('.scrollToTop').fadeIn();
        } else {
            $('.scrollToTop').fadeOut();
        }
    });

    //Click event to scroll up to top
    $('.scrollToTop').click(function() {
        $('html, body').animate({scrollTop : 0},750);
        return false;
    });
});
```